# Proof $\sigma (U) = \bigcap_{U \subset \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F} - \sigma - \text{Algebra of } \Omega} \mathcal{F} $ is sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a random class of subsets from $\Omega $.

Through

$$\sigma (\mathcal U) = \bigcap_{\mathcal U \subseteq \mathcal{F}\text{ and } \mathcal{F} \text{ is a } \sigma\text{-algebra on } \Omega} \mathcal{F} $$

a $\sigma$ algebra is given, i.e. the minimal $\sigma$ algebra, which contains $\mathcal U$.

How can one prove that $\sigma(\mathcal U)$ is really a $\sigma$-algebra?

This is what I did. Let $U$ and $V$ denote two subsets of a nonempty set $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal F$ denote the smallest sigma-algebra containing $U$ and $\mathcal G$  the smallest sigma-algebra containing $V$.

- If $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal V$ and $\mathcal F\ne \mathcal V$. Then, either $U=\varnothing$ or $U=\Omega$.
- If $\mathcal F=\mathcal U$. Then, either $U=V$ or $U=\Omega\setminus V$.

But I don't think that's the answer to what is being asked for.
I don't know how I can check the three properties (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Definition) on what is given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, intersections tend to behave nicely when every member of the intersection is closed under an operation. For example,  $\emptyset$ is contained in every such $\mathcal{F}$ so it is contained in their intersection, $\sigma(U)$. Using the same argument you can guarantee that the other properties hold. For the closure under complementation, let $S \in \sigma(U)$. Then, by definition, $S$ belongs to every member $\mathcal{F}$ of the intersection. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra we have $\Omega \setminus S \in \mathcal{F}$ so
$$\Omega \setminus S \in \bigcap_{\;\quad U \subseteq \mathcal{F} \\ \mathcal{F} \text{ is a }\sigma\text{-algebra}}  \mathcal{F} = \sigma(U).$$

Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: Can we just take an interval $(a,b)$ in $S$ and say that every of these countable open intervals lies in $\sigma$? Since a $\sigma$ algebra is stable when it comes to intersections, the countable part also lies in $\sigma$?

Comment: Why take an interval? You need to take $\{S_n\}$ a countable family of sets in $\sigma(U)$. Then all the $S_n$ belong in every $\mathcal{F}$ so their intersection lies in every such $\mathcal{F}$ and therefore in $\sigma(U)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let it be that $\mathcal F_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ for every $i\in I$.

Then it can be proved *straightforwardly* that $\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal F_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

By *straighforwardly* I mean that you only have to check that the collection is closed under complements and under countable unions (and is not empty).

Not really difficult and it shows immediately that the $\sigma(\mathcal U)$ defined in your question is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.